# Как можно реализовать дроплист с массивом классов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу сделать так, чтобы выбранные блоки (у которых класс *`nowselected`*, были в дроплисте `select` с текстом внутри блока, а если еще раз кликнуть по блоку (выбор блока отменится и соответственно класс будет `nonselected`), то он уберется из дроплиста) 
Пока ничего придумать не получается, только идея есть, что отслеживать `onclick` по блокам и проверять, если класс поменялся на `nowselected`, то добавляем в массив, если на `nonselected`, то удаляем из массив и меняем `html` в дроплисте, но не уверен, что это будет корректно работать

```js
  $('.nonselected').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('nowselected');
    });
```

```css
.nonselected{
    background-color: #35AAAA;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.nowselected{
  background-color: #E5C600;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
<div id="user1">
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="user2">
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="user3">
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
  <div class="nonselected">
  number 1
  </div>
    <div class="nonselected">
  number 2
  </div>
    <div class="nonselected">
  number 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А чего не уверены. Допишите. Если будут ошибки ли затык - поправим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При клике пересобираются данные для options в select. Код грязноват, только для демонстрации идеи.

```js
var selects = $('.select');

$('.nonselected').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('nowselected');
  var selected = $('.nowselected');

  for (var counter = 0; counter < selects.length; counter++) {
    $(selects[counter]).empty();
    $(selects[counter]).append('<option>Выберите номер</option>');
    for (var idx = 0; idx < selected.length; idx++) {
      var opt = '<option>' + selected[idx].innerText + '</option>';
      $(selects[counter]).append(opt);
    }
    if (selected.length == 0) {
     var opt = '<option> Выберите номер </option>';
      $(selects[counter]).append(opt);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.nonselected {
  background-color: #35AAAA;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.nowselected {
  background-color: #E5C600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="banner-message">
  <div id="user1">
    <select class="select">
      <option>Выберите номер</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="user2">
    <select class="select">
    <option>Выберите номер</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="user3">
    <select class="select">
    <option>Выберите номер</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="nonselected">
    number 1
  </div>
  <div class="nonselected">
    number 2
  </div>
  <div class="nonselected">
    number 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: чуть-чуть доделал, чтоб поле не было пустым, спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. В свою очередь чуть дописал. Так как при клике содержимое select полностью обновляется. И пустую option нужно отрисовывать заново.